# error TS2339: Property 'log' does not exist on type '{ new (): Console; prototype: Console; }'

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
class helloworld 
{
   constructor(public message: string){}
}
var hello = new helloworld('hello vishal');
Console.log(hello.message);
```

I am getting this error at Console.log statement
you can see the error clearly in the image i posted below

[image]

Comment: try `console.log` with lowercase `c`.

Comment: To be clear, `Console` seems to be a constructor function that produced the `console` object. `console instanceof Console; // true` Though it doesn't let you actually invoke it in Firefox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have typo in your script. [JavaScript is Case sensitive](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/0596000480/ch02s02.html). Enter:

```
console.log(hello.message);
```

Instead `Console.log(hello.message);`

Answer (score 2):

You should write

```
console.log(hello.message)
```

JS is case sensitive.